# post-commit hook telling the parent repo to update the link to the the submodule in bit bucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-submodules, githooks

In **Bit bucket**
Every time I push a commit to the submodule I need to update the parent repo to the latest commit in the submodule. Is there any automatic way to do that in the remote?

Every time push a commit in the submodule repo i want the parent to automatically point to the latest commit of the child repo. I thought of  post-commit hook telling the parent repo to update the link to the the submodule in bit bucket .Please suggest if its possible and how?

1. go to a checked-out parent repository
2. execute git submodule update --remote: that would update all submodules to their latest master (by default) commit.
3. add, commit, and push

Please give references for this for bitbucket

Comment: You're almost on the right track **except for BitBucket**. You cannot do that on the remote side, everything must be done locally. At the remote side (BitBucket or any other hosting) a submodule doesn't know it's a submodule; it could be a submodule of a hundred of superprojects.

Comment: @phd, Thanks for commenting, but had a small query , even if submodule doesn't know that its a submodule but is there a way where we could create a hook where that could run the git commands that we run locally in an automated way

Comment: Yes but again — that must be a local hook, where a repository is a submodule.

Comment: @phd, any other workaround you can suggest on how to automate this? even if it is in local.

Comment: A post-commit hook in the submodule that goes to the checked-out parent repository, unsets `GIT_DIR`, executes `git submodule update --remote`, add, commit, push.

Comment: Yeah that was the plan @phd , but not aware of how to setup in bitbucket , any reference please

Comment: You started from the beginning. No, you cannot do that with bitbucket, only with a local clone.